# bind is not working in my C program

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

This is the code which I wrote to create a socket and bind it to the address and port:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char APPRESSMESSAGE[] = "APRESS,For Profesionals By Professional!\n";
    int SimpleSocket = 0;
    int SimplePort = 0;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    SimpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (SimpleSocket == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create the socket !\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "socket created\n");
    }
    SimplePort = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct sockaddr_in SimpleServer;
    bzero(&SimpleServer, sizeof(SimpleServer));
    SimpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SimpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    SimpleServer.sin_port = htons(SimplePort);
    int return_status;
    return_status = bind(SimpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&SimpleServer, sizeof(SimpleServer));
    if (return_status == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "bind completed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not bind to socket\n");
        close(SimpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I am expecting the output to be:

```
socket created
bind completed.
```

But the result is "could not bind to socket".
What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: did you check the documentation for `bind`? what does it say about the return states and errors?

Comment: on success it returns zero.

Comment: Well, on fail, what is errno?

Comment: And if it's not 0, check errno to find out why it failed. Without errno, we've got a few hundred possibilities. Most likely is the port you want is already taken. Another possibility is bad input that atoi is failing to convert causing you to attempt to bind port 0. Prefer strtol to atoi as strtol will tell you when it fails to convert.

Comment: Also, your indentation is err... 'less than optimal', and this makes the code difficult to follow:(.

Comment: Use a debugger to check all the arguments to bind().

Comment: Note that professionals spell consistently and correctly.  They also avoid unused variables in programs shown on SO.

Comment: They also don't report their own error messages. Instead they report the ones that come with the system. Expecting others to debug your own message is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

> the result is "could not bind to socket". What can be the possible reason for this ?

Quoting from `man bind` (on a Linux system), some possible errors (there are more for Unix sockets, but this is a TCP socket):

```
ERRORS
    EACCES The address is protected, and the user is not the superuser.

    EADDRINUSE
           The given address is already in use.

    EBADF  sockfd is not a valid descriptor.

    EINVAL The socket is already bound to an address.

    ENOTSOCK
           sockfd is a descriptor for a file, not a socket.
```

You could reduce the number of possibilities to investigate significantly by checking the value of `errno`, or by simply using a call to `perror`:

```
if (bind(SimpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&SimpleServer,sizeof(SimpleServer)) == 0) {
    fprintf(stdout,"bind completed\n");
}
else {
    perror("Could not bind to socket");
    close(SimpleSocket);
    exit(1);
}
```